# Are "grúa" and "grulla" etymologically related?

Tags: etimología, animales, construcción-y-obra

In English, mechanical "cranes" are thus named for their likeness to the bird, "crane".

In Spanish, the mechanical crane is called a *grúa* and the bird a *grulla*; is this similarity a coincidence, or are the words also related?

Comment: Also related with **pedigree** (esp: pedigrí from the french *pie du grue*) and maybe with **Gruyere** - the cheese, although this second one is not very clear. Maybe the Swiss village of Gruyeres was a place with lots of cranes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are indeed related:

> ... **grúa, utilizada en castellano desde el siglo XV para designar una máquina destinada a levantar pesos, por su semejanza con la figura de una grulla, de largo pescuezo y prolongado pico.** Mucho más clara que en español resalta esta semejanza entre la grulla y las grúas para nuestros vecinos europeos, que en sus idiomas disponen de una única palabra para designar ambos conceptos:
>
> - *Kran* en alemán,
> - *crane* en inglés,
> - *grua* en catalán,
> - *grue* en francés,
> - *gru* en italiano;
>
> todos ellos, por cierto, de origen tan netamente onomatopéyico como nuestra grulla.
>
> - [*Parentescos sorprendentes: grúa y grulla*](http://www.elcastellano.org/parent01.html) (elcastellano.org)

Further, they are even cognate to the English words via a PIE root:

[image]

Interestingly, in Latin [another mechanical device](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grus#Latin) (a type of siege engine) was also named for its word for crane, "grus", due to the physical likeness.

Comment: RAE's dictionary confirms this, both _[grulla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JaEiUvK)_ and _[grúa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JZqgk3z)_ come from Latin _grus, gruis_ 'crane'.

Comment: Dutch seemingly distinguishes (mechanical) "crane" from "crane bird" (kraan/ kraanvogel), but that addition of "-bird" is relatively recent; same with the German bird "kranich" where many birds get the "-ich" suffix; the bird name precedes the tool and hence its name. The root in germanic seems onomatopaeic for the noise they make, similar to the Greek root for stork.